# dropzone.js removeLink URL defintion

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone 4.3.0 currently.

```
function HiddenNotesDropZone() {
        $("#HiddenAttachments").dropzone({
            maxFiles: 2000,
            parallelUploads: 1,
            maxFilesize: 2048,
            filesizeBase: 1024,
            disablePreviews: true,
            clickable: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            createImageThumbnails: false,
            url: "/api/Quotes/HiddenAttachments",
            success: function(file, response) {
                if (response !== -1) {
                    fileIds.push(response);
                }
                file._removeLink.href = "DeleteUpload/"+response;
            }
        });
    }
```

This does not seem like it would be the proper means in which to set the specific thumbnails remove URL, which I would like to set to an api similar to the upload path however with the response Id which is the server database record Id. This might be a security flaw however for now I am willing to accept it as I don't know many means around it at the moment.

```
file._removeLink.href = "DeleteUpload/"+response;
```

It seems to function as I would like but it just doesn't seem correct or best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out I could do this

```
function HiddenNotesDropZone() {
        $("#HiddenAttachments").dropzone({
            maxFiles: 2000,
            parallelUploads: 1,
            maxFilesize: 2048,
            filesizeBase: 1024,
            disablePreviews: true,
            clickable: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            createImageThumbnails: false,
            url: "/api/Quotes/HiddenAttachments",
            success: function (file, response) {
                file.Id = response;
                if (response !== -1) {
                    fileIds.push(response);
                }
            },
            removedfile: function(file) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/api/Quotes/DeleteAttachment/"+file.Id,
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Specifically by adding the Id to the file which is the response I can use the response to produce the api call to delete the file ID.